# How to know if element comes out the screen in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I try to know if an element comes out the screen in my application. I see that when my element it outside the screen, onDesappear is not trigger. I don't know if there is an other solution to trigger this?

I made an example to explain what I want. I have a circle with an offset to force it out of the screen to a certain degree:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  
  @ObservedObject var location: LocationProvider = LocationProvider()
  @State var heading: Double = 0
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Circle()
        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
        .background(Color.red)
        .clipShape(Circle())
        .foregroundColor(Color.clear)
        .offset(y: 300)
        .border(Color.black)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(self.heading))
        .onReceive(self.location.heading) { heading in
          self.heading = heading
        }
        .onDisappear(perform: { print("Desappear") })
      Text("\(self.heading)")
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe it's possible with geometryReader?

Comment: What do you mean by "comes out of the screen"? Do you mean "exceeds the bounds of the screen"?

Comment: Offset does not remove view from screen, view remains on the same place - it is just drawn at different location.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, exceeds the bounds of the screen